# I have a stopover in Iceland with Iceland Air, do I have to collect and check back in my luggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, stopovers, reykjavik, icelandair

Iceland Air offers free stopovers in Reykjavik when flying between North America to the rest of Europe (I specifically booked a multi-city ticket with a stopover in Reykjavik). Neither on my ticket nor on [their website](http://www.icelandair.ca/information/at-the-airport/customs-immigration/) did I see a mention of luggage collection and check in in Reykjavik. Since this is a stopover (and not a layover), I am wondering if Iceland Air stores my bag for a day (my stopover is of about 20 hours) or if I should take care of it in Reykjavik (and find some locker in the airport/in the city) [while I visit the area](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21224/stopover-in-iceland-w-icelandair-can-i-leave-the-airport).

So, for Iceland Air free stopover policy, is Iceland Air asking me to collect my luggage in Reykjavik airport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I checked in for Icelandair, with a 10 day stopover the checking online page stated 'your stopover is longer than 24 hours, you can not check in for the second leg' which I think is an indication that up to 24 hours is norm for them.

But in case they do not want to keep your luggage, I found you [a link to a luggage storage at the airport](http://www.kefairport.is/English/For-the-passenger/Luggage-storage-/).

> Information about Bílahótel Luggage Storage.
>   Our Luggage storage is located 500 meters from the departure side of the airport. We are behind the Airport Hotel. Same building as Geysir and Sixt Car Rentals.
>   The office is open from 05:00 – 17:00 (05:00-21:00 15 May – 15 Sept). The price for each bag the first week is 5 Euros per day and 1 Euro per day after that. The price for odd-size luggage the first week is 6 Euros per day and 2 Euros per day after that.

That page also has a contact us link.